# Novikov Ring Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a four part question involving the Novikov ring.

[image]

---

For part (1), I have:

$(\Sigma_{\gamma\in \tau}a_{\gamma}t^\gamma) +_{N} (\Sigma_{\gamma\in \tau}b_{\gamma}t^\gamma) =\Sigma_{\gamma\in \tau}(a_{\gamma}+b_{\gamma})t^\gamma$

We know that $(a_{\gamma}+b_{\gamma})\in \mathbb{Z}$ because $a_{\gamma} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b_{\gamma} \in \mathbb{Z}$

But I am unsure how to show that it satisfies the condition:
[image]

Similarly, I am unsure about how to prove closure for $\cdot_{N}$

---

For part (2), I just need to prove that it is an integral domain, so I must show that it is commutative, and I must show that it has no zero divisors. Again, I am unsure how to start the zero divisors portion of this part.

---

For part (3), I know the units in this ring must act as "multiplicative inverses", but I am unsure on how to express them.

---

For part (4), I must show that the Novikov ring can be generated by a single element. I am unsure how to approach this as well.

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *But I am unsure how to show that it satisfies the condition:* that condition is give to you as a hypothesis. You don't have to prove it.

Comment: *For part (4), I must show that the Novikov ring can be generated by a single element.* that is not what a principal ideal ring is. You'd have to show every ideal is generated by a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of what you're looking for is contained in Chapter 4 of Salamon and Hofer's paper [Floer Homology and Novikov Rings](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/lowdim.pdf).